# How to start forkserver after creating multiprocessing.Array in python 3.6 in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I have a giant float array (about 40 GB) that I would like to share with 20 parallel loaders for them to put their data. The main parent process will get data from this array.

I would like to avoid the default mode of multiprocessing since it would copy the entire process, which contains other object unused in children.

I was thinking it would be beneficial if I can create a shared multiprocessing array and start a forkserver before creating objects specific to the main parent process. Then, when I use multiprocessing.Process, it would fork from the forkserver which has shared array but nothing else created afterwards.

However, I can't really get this work. If I do multiprocessing.set_start_method("forkserver") then Array created afterwards will not be available to the forkserver. I tried creating Array first and then setting the start method but it raises error for the starting method being already set when the Array is created. I also tried creating a shared array with multiprocessing.get_context("forkserver").Array(), but then the forkserver does not have a variable associated with this array inside, so I fail to access the shared array in multiprocessing.Process.

Is there any way to make it work? Does my approach even make sense? What is the most efficient way for python processes to share a large array but nothing else?

Comment: I also deal with this same problem. I'm going to use an IPC shared memory library. If you found another solution, could you share it ? Thanks !